# Copy and Paste Value dynamically

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

Sorry, I'm a novice within VBA. But I'm trying to copy a cell value if condition is met and paste it in another row on the spreadsheet dynamically. So if cell value Q13 is = "45" then it will paste that value in the P column in the last active row.

```
Sub Copy_Values()
Dim range1 As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Set range1 = Sheet2.Range("Q13")

For Each Cell In range1
    If Cell.Value = "45" Then
    With Sheet2
    .Cells(Cell.Row, "Q13").Copy Sheet2.Range("P").End(xlUp)
        End With
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

So I 've since edited the code because I already had a macro in place where once I click a button, cell Q13 changes based on other values in the spreadsheet, and the value in Q13 is then copied into the E column in the same sheet. However, I need to make an adjustment so that when cell Q13 reads 45, it gets pasted in the P column and not in the E column (maybe an if not statement or something). I thought I would just incorporate this macro separately, but now realizing it has to be one function. The code below is very wrong, so perhaps someone could help me tidy it up:

```
Sub Test()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet2
Dim range1 As Range: Set range1 = ws.Range("Q13")
Dim Cell As Range
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range("B2:B" & Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row)
    Dim R As Range
    Set R = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp) 'last cell in Column E with data
    For Each Cell In range1
    If Cell.Value = "45" Then
        NextRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        Cell.Copy ws.Range("P" & NextRow)
    If Len(R.Value) > 0 Then Set R = R.Offset(1)
    R.Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("Q13").Value
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).value = cell.value`

Comment: If you just interested in values, then there is no need for copy/paste at all and a value transfer will do just fine. However, if you check a single cell for it's value, then there doesn't seem to be any need for a value transfer at all.

Comment: Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way, but I have a macro  in place where once I click a button, cell Q13 changes based on other values in the spreadsheet, and the value in Q13 is  the copied into another column in the same sheet. However, when cell Q13 reads 45, I need that value to get pasted in the P column. I thought I would just incorporate this macro seperately, but now realizing I may need to combine the two.

Answer (score 0):

The following will achieve your desired result, it will dynamically get the next empty row in Column P and paste the value there:

```
Sub Copy_Values()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet2
Dim range1 As Range: Set range1 = ws.Range("Q13")
Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In range1
    If Cell.Value = "45" Then
        NextRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        Cell.Copy ws.Range("P" & NextRow)
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

**Update:**

If you are only looking to check for a single cell (Q13), you could simplify the code getting rid of the For Loop, as below:

```
Sub Copy_Values()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet2
    If ws.Range("Q13").Value = "45" Then
        NextRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        ws.Range("Q13").Copy ws.Range("P" & NextRow)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit of overkill to have a `For` loop for a one cell range, unless you plan to expand in the future.

```
Sub Copy_Values()
    Dim range1 As Range
    Set range1 = Sheet2.Range("Q13")

    If range1.Value = "45" Then
        range1.Copy Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End If

End Sub
```